# Does ATI Radeon HD 3400 series supports OpenCL at all?

Tags: opencl, ati

If yes - where should be file OpenCL.dll ?
Trying to find in

C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository

but no success... :-(

I need this file for normal work of project I worked on.
I have hope that i could stole it from computer with NVidia and CUDA 5.5 and it will works on my computer with ATI Radeon HD 3400...

Could anyone give some suggest?

Comment: I tried on HD4800 series of a friend, opencl bindings for java (jocl)failed but HD5000 series worked. Maybe AMD brought down the support for HD3400 opencl. Also even HD4850 was supposed to be in beta-opencl compatible so HD3400 could be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "steal" the OpenCL.dll, but if the driver does not support OpenCL it will still fail (crash). Since the OpenCL.dll is just a stub to the inner ICD and driver. Your best choise is to install AMD SDK and use OpenCL in CPU mode only.

As far as I know, GPUs below 4xxx do not have OpenCL support. (There may be exceptions)

Comment: I'm almost positive that 4000 series was the first to support opencl. I tried unsuccessfully to find an exception to this rule.

Comment: Here's an official confirmation for 4xxx as a minimum: http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/142521 Note1: 4xxx support OpenCL 1.0 only!  Note2: You need 5xxx card (CL 1.2) for the AMD APP SDK!

Answer (score 0):

It not listed as  a conformant product by Khronos on the OpenCL standards organization

Check at

http://www.khronos.org/conformance/adopters/conformant-products

I suspect you will be wasting your time attempting to use the OpenCL DLL.  Every little problem could be due ton its non-conformance.  So  why  bother when  a Radeon HD 5450 is only $70 at NewEgg??

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814161354

Surely you employer is not that cheap they can't  afford $70?

Or you can use OpenCL on the CPU for free.